# Module support in iOS Static Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, module, xcode6, static-libraries

I have multiple static iOS libraries (Objective-C) that I would like to add module support to.

By that I mean the use of @import statements instead of needing to use a bridging header to support swift.

Facebook, and Parse have recently added this feature to their SDKs but I can't find any documentation as to how they did it. Keep in mind that these SDKs STILL target iOS 7 so they are not simply dynamic frameworks (which would only support iOS8).

Can anyone explain exactly how I can go about doing this?